# Static transforms using tf2

Tags: ros

I'm trying to publish a static transform using tf2. The end goal is to run turtlesim which subscribes to the static transform and moves accordingly. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you check the `static_transform_publisher` of tf? See [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher).

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look at the documentation. I'm doing the tutorials but I didn't find them too comprehensive, hence the doubt.